# C: Преобразование русской строки в нижний регистр?

Tags: c, строки, gcc

Возможно, дубликат, но решений я не нашёл для GCC 8. Читал про _strlwr, но функция описана в документации MSVC, а в string.h для GCC не нашёл подобную. Использование tolower(char) не меняет русский символ. Что можно сделать?

Comment: `towlower` [описание](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cwctype/towlower/)

Comment: Про ``tolower`` читали?

Comment: Насколько знаю, универсального способа не существует. Это связано с наличием различных кодировок. Для русского это koi8-r, cp1251, unicode (которого четыре вида), iso8859-5 ...

Comment: Наверняка вопрос про unicode, все остальное надо конвертировать, например `iconv`

Comment: Короче говоря, мазохизм сплошной. Пошёл запускать винду